# How to get multiple template types list in SharePoint using Rest

Tags: rest, sharepoint-2013, sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-rest-api

I am trying to list all the custom lists and events list.

here is my code in the URL

***url:"http://example.com/_api/web/lists/?filter=BaseTemplate eq 100 and BaseTemplate eq 106 and Hidden eq false"***

if I do only one template it works but when I do multiple it returns nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use the below endpoing instead:

```
/_api/web/lists/?$filter=(BaseTemplate eq 100 or BaseTemplate eq 106) and Hidden eq false
```